# How do I increase the upload size in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis7, iis, windows, microsoft

I can't upload more than 2 MB. I read that IIS' max. upload size is 4 (actually 4,2) GB and ASP.NET's is 2 GB.

I really can't think of an alternative. I could change the max. upload size in PHP but IIS isn't compatible with this causing the server not to accept uploads over 2 MB still.

But even if 4,2 GB can be uploaded, how can I configure that? I've tried everything but it just doesn't work!

I was also told that it can be increased via ASP.NET but I don't think it is to be honest. And even if, how?

What have I tried?

## Change the web.config

I added this to the `web.config` file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="xxx" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

## Request filtering

I went to IIS -> `servername` -> Sites -> `sitename` -> Request Filtering -> Edit Feature Settings... and changed the `Maximum allowed content length (Bytes)` field there. Is that the one I need to change?

[image]

## Change it in PHP

I changed the `upload_max_filesize` section:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = xxxM
```

to something else in the `php.ini`. It increased the limit in PHP but IIS must be compatible with that change, which it isn't, unfortunately.

Yes, I restarted IIS every time I made a change, but without effect unfortunately.

The error message I get all the time is:

[image]

I suggested to my 'client' to use Apache but he wants to use IIS, so switching is not really an option.

Comment: Does implementing it [this way](http://www.webtrenches.com/post.cfm/iis7-file-upload-size-limits) help?

Comment: I am still having this issue. Anyone?

Comment: Are you trying to do this at the Server Level Or the Site Level?

Comment: @eyoung100 Don't care, as long as it works :P

Comment: Use the method I gave you above on a per site basis.  You can't use this with the DEFAULT_WEB_SITE as the default doesn't read web.config

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `maxAllowedContentLength`, not `maxRequestLength` to up the allowed upload size for IIS. the former is the IIS request length limit, the latter is the ASP.NET request length limit.

Also important to know is that `maxAllowedContentLength` is the length in bytes, whereas `maxRequestLength` is the length in kilobytes.

See [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327452/which-gets-priority-maxrequestlength-or-maxallowedcontentlength/7196235#7196235) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change/increase `post_max_size` and `memory_limit` in the `php.ini`?
Both values also affect file upload size and must be larger than `upload_max_filesize`.

See the PHP documentation for further reference:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

Comment: Yes, I have, without effect.

Comment: (As you can see in the question.)

Comment: Sorry it didn't help, but your question doesn't mention that you tried this.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but it does... (the last one)

Comment: You write you changed upload_max_filesize, doesn't say that you also aligned post_max_size and memory_limit variables to it.

Comment: Oh, OK, I see what you mean now... sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the upload size in following ways;

(1) One of the methods is

```
< system.webServer > 
  < security > 
    < requestFiltering > 
      < requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength= “214783648” / > 
    < / requestFiltering > 
  < / security > 
< / system.webBrowser >
```

(2) Using a GUI: http://www.web-site-scripts.com/knowledge-base/article/AA-00696/0/Increasing-maximum-allowed-size-for-uploads-on-IIS7.html